# problem with dictionaries inserted inside a list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I've done a lot of research but I just can't understand it. I'm trying to create a little program that returns all the currencies within a dictionary and then puts them in a list, but when I print it out I get this

```
l_report = []
dict_report = {}

def maximum_volume():
    global dict_report
    list_volume = [] #LIST CONTAINING CURRENCY VOLUMES

    for elements in currencies:
        list_volume.append(elements['quote']['USD']['volume_24h']) 
    for elements in currencies:
        if max(list_volume) == elements['quote']['USD']['volume_24h']:
            dict_report ={
                'max_volume' : elements['name']
            }
            l_report.append(dict_report)


def top10():
    global dict_report
    list_top = [] #LIST CONTAINING THE VALUES OF CURRENCIES WITH A POSITIVE INCREMENT
    for elements in currencies:
        if elements['quote']['USD']['percent_change_24h'] > 0:
            list_top.append(elements['quote']['USD']['percent_change_24h'])

    top10_sorted = sorted(list_top, key=lambda x: float(x), reverse=True) 
    for num in top10_sorted[:10]:
        for elements in currencies:       
            if num == elements['quote']['USD']['percent_change_24h']:
                dict_report={
                    'name' : elements['name'],
                    'percent': num
                }
                l_report.append(dict_report)

maximum_volume()
top10()

for k in l_report:
    print(k['name'])  


        KeyError: 'name'
```

Comment: In the function `maximum_volume` the dictionary `dict_report` which gets appended to `l_report` does not have the key `name`.  Dictionaries in `l_report` list appended by `maximum_volume()`  will not have `name` key, hence the error.

Comment: How can I solve the problem? If I insert the empty key, I won't solve anything right?

Comment: I would make two different lists to store the maximum volume and top10, instead of appending it to the same global `l_report`.

Comment: `currencies` is  not defined. where does this come from ?   you should add this so that users can replicate the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And `dict_report` should not be global otherwise you will have the same dictionary instance with overwritten values appended to the list `l_report`.

Comment: currencies = to the coinmarketcap api request which returns a json dictionary with all the data

Comment: finally thank you, you have given me very good hints to solve the problem